# How to find where a service is installed to? C#

Tags: c#-4.0, service

Is it possible to find out through .Net whereabouts a service is installed to?

```
var temp = from sc in ServiceController.GetServices()
where sc.ServiceName == "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"
select sc;
```

However the servicecontroller doesn't give me the path I want, notably the "Path to Execute" found in the service properties dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this [code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ServiceController.aspx)